# how to make scroll bar appear only on table body not table header

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mui-datatable

`   using mui table component to display table data in react component, the scrollbar appears to be on table header[ui for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDv5J.png) which is not intended how to make it scroll only the table body part of the the component
: This component provides a container for the table and includes custom scrollbar styling (id="custom-scrollbar") and conditional CSS classes based on the isScrollable prop. The sx prop is used to set the maximum height of the container based on different conditions.

: This component is rendered when isGridLoading is true, indicating that the table is in a loading state.

: This component represents the table itself with the stickyHeader attribute set to true, which keeps the table header fixed when scrolling.

: This component is responsible for rendering the table header and receives props related to sorting functionality.

: This component contains the table rows and cells.

: This component is conditionally rendered when isSearchByColumn is true and provides a search functionality based on the headCells prop.

Table Rows: The code maps over the rows array and renders individual  components for each row. Each row is identified by a key based on the rowIndex.

Table Cells: Within each row, the code maps over the headCells array and renders individual  components for each cell. The align prop is set based on the alignment property of the corresponding head object. Conditional styling is applied based on different conditions, such as row?.touched, rowIndex == 0, etc.

: This component represents a custom input/select element based on the label prop. It receives various props related to data handling, rendering options, and interaction.

Additional Rows: The code renders additional rows based on different conditions. These rows contain specific cells with custom content, such as totals or spanning rows.

Conditional Rendering: Depending on different conditions (!isGridLoading, !rows.length > 0), a message indicating "No Records Found" is displayed using the motion.div component from the Framer Motion library.

```
<TableContainer
          id="custom-scrollbar"
          className={
            isScrollable && `h-56 w-52 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll `
          }
          sx={{
            maxHeight:
              tableHeight != "" ? tableHeight : windowHeight > 800 ? 550 : 316,
          }}
        >
          {isGridLoading && <LinearProgress />}
          <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
            <EnhancedTableHead
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows?.length}
            />

            <TableBody>
              {isSearchByColumn && (
                <Search
                  headCells={headCells}
                  searchValue={searchValue}
                  setSearchValue={getSearchValue}
                />
              )}
              {rows.length > 0 &&
                rows
                  .slice(0, isScrollable ? 100 : numberOfRecords)
                  .sort(getComparator(order, orderBy))
                  .map((row, rowIndex) => {
                    const labelId = `checkbox-${rowIndex}`;
                    return (
                      <>
                        <TableRow
                          className={row?.touched && "bg-gray-lightest"}
                          key={rowIndex}
                        >
                          {headCells.map((head, headIndex) => {
                            return (
                              <TableCell
                                align={head?.alignment}
                                onMouseEnter={() => showActions(rowIndex)}
                                key={headIndex}
                                style={{
                                  textAlign:
                                    row[head.key] === undefined && "center",
                                }}
                                className={`${rowIndex == 0 &&
                                  "border-t border-purple-light"
                                  } `}
                              >
                                <TypeSelector
                                  rows={rows}
                                  setRows={setRows}
                                  headLabel={head.label}
                                  row={row}
                                  labelId={labelId}
                                  billStatus={row.status}
                                  label={head.type}
                                  fieldKey={head.key}
                                  value={row[head.key]}
                                  selectOptions={selectOptions}
                                  options={row[head.key]}
                                  rowIndex={rowIndex}
                                  isActionsOnHover={isActionsOnHover}
                                  currentActionIndex={currentActionIndex}
                                  actions={head.actions}
                                  navigationPath={head.navigationPath}
                                  state={state}
                                  dispatch={dispatch}
                                  setSelectedInput={setSelectedInput}
                                  setSelectedRate={setSelectedRate}
                                  selectedRate={selectedRate}
                                  selectedInput={selectedInput}
                                  isCheckboxChecked={isCheckboxChecked}
                                  setIsCheckboxChecked={setIsCheckboxChecked}
                                  disableDropdown={disableDropdown}
                                  disableCheckbox={disableCheckbox}
                                  disableInput={disableInput}
                                />
                              </TableCell>
                            );
                          })}
                        </TableRow>
                      </>
                    );
                  })}

              {rows.length > 0 && showRecieptGridTotal && (
                <TableRow className="w-full">
                  {recieptOptions.map((option, index) => (
                    <TableCell
                      className={` ${"border-t border-purple-light  "} `}
                    >
                      {option.type == "text" && (
                        <span className="font-extrabold">{option.value}</span>
                      )}
                      {option.type == "input" && (
                        <input
                          style={{ width: "70px", height: "20px" }}
                          className={` disabled:bg-gray-50 font-extrabold disabled:text-gray-500 disabled:border-gray-200 border w-full px-2 focus:outline-none text-regular`}
                          value={
                            !disableTotalInput
                              ? discountAmountTotal
                              : discountTotal
                          }
                          //  defaultValue={option.value}
                          disabled={!disableTotalInput}
                          onChange={(e) => setDiscountTotal(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              )}

              {rows.length > 0 && showTotalAmount && (
                <TableRow className="w-full">
                  {amountOptions.map((option, index) => (
                    <TableCell
                      className={` ${"border-t border-purple-light  "} `}
                    >
                      {option.type == "text" && (
                        <span className="font-extrabold">{option.value}</span>
                      )}
                      {option.type == "input" && (
                        <input
                          style={{ width: "70px", height: "20px" }}
                          className={` disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500 font-extrabold disabled:border-gray-200 border w-full px-2 focus:outline-none text-regular`}
                          value={
                            !disableTotalInput
                              ? discountAmountTotal
                              : discountTotal
                          }
                          //  defaultValue={option.value}
                          disabled={!disableTotalInput}
                          onChange={(e) => setDiscountTotal(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              )}
              {rows.length > 0 && showOpdDueAmount && (
                <TableRow className="w-full">
                  {opdDueamountOptions.map((option, index) => (
                    <TableCell
                      className={` ${"border-t border-purple-light  "} `}
                    >
                      {option.type == "text" && (
                        <span className="font-extrabold">{option.value}</span>
                      )}
                      {option.type == "input" && (
                        <input
                          style={{ width: "70px", height: "20px" }}
                          className={` disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500 disabled:border-gray-200 font-extrabold  border w-full px-2 focus:outline-none text-regular`}
                          value={
                            !disableTotalInput
                              ? discountAmountTotal
                              : discountTotal
                          }
                          //  defaultValue={option.value}
                          disabled={!disableTotalInput}
                          onChange={(e) => setDiscountTotal(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              )}
              {rows.length > 0 && showGridTotal && (
                <TableRow className="w-full">
                  {options.map((option, index) => (
                    <TableCell
                      className={` ${"border-t border-purple-light  "} `}
                    >
                      {option.type == "text" && (
                        <span className="font-extrabold">{option.value}</span>
                      )}
                      {option.type == "input" && (
                        <input
                          style={{ width: "70px", height: "20px" }}
                          className={` disabled:bg-gray-50 disabled:text-gray-500 font-extrabold disabled:border-gray-200 border w-full px-2 focus:outline-none text-regular`}
                          value={
                            !disableTotalInput
                              ? discountAmountTotal
                              : discountTotal
                          }
                          //  defaultValue={option.value}
                          disabled={!disableTotalInput}
                          onChange={(e) => setDiscountTotal(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              )}

              {spanningRow?.map((row) => (
                <TableRow>
                  {row.map((rowData) => (
                    <TableCell colSpan={rowData.colspan}>
                      <TypeSelector
                        fieldLabel={rowData.label}
                        readOnly={rowData.readOnly}
                        value={rowData.value}
                        label={rowData.type}
                        options={rowData.value}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
          {!isGridLoading && !rows.length > 0 ? (
            <motion.div
              initial={{
                opacity: 0,
              }}
              animate={{
                opacity: 1,
              }}
              transition={{
                duration: 1,
              }}
              className="capitalize text-gray-light text-center pt-4 text-lg"
            >
              No Records Found
            </motion.div>
          ) : null}
        </TableContainer>
```

i was trying to make it as simple not to change the rest of the code`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).